# Swift Insert Element At Specific Index

Tags: ios, swift

I'm doing a project that has an online streaming of music.

1. I have an array of object called **Song** - Each song in that array of Song has a URL from SoundCloud.
2. Fast enumerate each song and then call the SoundCloud **Resolve API** to get the direct stream URL of each song. And store each direct url into an Array and load to my Player.

This seems to be really easy, but the #2 step is asynchronous and so each direct URL can be stored to a wrong index of array. I'm thinking to use the **Insert AtIndex** instead of **append** so I made a sample code in **Playground** cause all of my ideas to make the storing of direct URL retain its order, didn't work successfully.

```
var myArray = [String?]()

func insertElementAtIndex(element: String?, index: Int) {

    if myArray.count == 0 {
        for _ in 0...index {
            myArray.append("")
        }
    }

    myArray.insert(element, atIndex: index)
}

insertElementAtIndex("HELLO", index: 2)
insertElementAtIndex("WORLD", index: 5)
```

My idea is in this playground codes, it produces an error of course, and finally, my question would be: what's the right way to use this **insert atIndex** ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This line:

```
if myArray.count == 0 {
```

only gets called once, the first time it runs. Use this to get the array length to at least the index you're trying to add:

```
var myArray = [String?]()

func insertElementAtIndex(element: String?, index: Int) {

    while myArray.count <= index {
        myArray.append("")
    }

    myArray.insert(element, atIndex: index)
}
```

Comment: I would rewrite the whole loop conditional this way:

while myArray.count <= index

Answer (score 41):

Very easy now with Swift 3:

```
// Initialize the Array
var a = [1,2,3]

// Insert value '6' at index '2'
a.insert(6, atIndex:2)

print(a) //[1,2,6,3]
```

Comment: Failing to check that the index is legitimate will result in "Index out of range" when trying to access an index that's greater than a.count - 1. In this respect @Shades answer is superior.

Comment: if array is of String type, this error occurs `Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'String.Index'`

Answer (score 4):

swift 4

```
func addObject(){
   var arrayName:[String] = ["Name0", "Name1", "Name3"]
   arrayName.insert("Name2", at: 2)
   print("---> ",arrayName)
}

Output: 
---> ["Name0","Name1", "Name2", "Name3"]
```